# Google Dataflow: Coder for ZipInputStream

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to unzip some files (which themselves contain zipfiles) from google storage to google storage.

Thus, I have the following DoFn to collect the ZipInputStreams:

```
  static class UnzipFilesFN extends DoFn<GcsPath,ZipInputStream>{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7373250969860890761L;
public void processElement(ProcessContext c){
     GcsPath p = c.element();
     try{
         ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(p.toString()));
         c.output(zis);

     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){
         //
     }
  }
```

}

And the following custom sink to do the unzipping and writing part:

```
public static class ZipIO{    
  public static class Sink extends com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.Sink<ZipInputStream> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7414200726778377175L;
    final String unzipTarget;

      public Sink withDestinationPath(String s){
         if(s!=""){
             return new Sink(s);
         }
         else {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("must assign destination path");
         }

      }

      protected Sink(String path){
          this.unzipTarget = path;
      }

      @Override
      public void validate(PipelineOptions po){
          if(unzipTarget==null){
              throw new RuntimeException();
          }
      } 

      @Override
      public ZipFileWriteOperation createWriteOperation(PipelineOptions po){
          return new ZipFileWriteOperation(this);
      }

  }

  private static class ZipFileWriteOperation extends WriteOperation<ZipInputStream, UnzipResult>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7976541367499831605L;
    private final ZipIO.Sink sink;

      public ZipFileWriteOperation(ZipIO.Sink sink){
          this.sink = sink;
      }



      @Override
      public void initialize(PipelineOptions po) throws Exception{

      }

      @Override
      public void finalize(Iterable<UnzipResult> writerResults, PipelineOptions po) throws Exception {
         long totalFiles = 0;
         for(UnzipResult r:writerResults){
             totalFiles +=r.filesUnziped;
         }
         LOG.info("Unzipped {} Files",totalFiles);
      }  

      @Override
      public ZipIO.Sink getSink(){
          return sink;
      }

      @Override
      public ZipWriter createWriter(PipelineOptions po) throws Exception{
          return new ZipWriter(this);
      }

  }

  private static class ZipWriter extends Writer<ZipInputStream, UnzipResult>{
      private final ZipFileWriteOperation writeOp;
      private long totalUnzipped = 0;

      ZipWriter(ZipFileWriteOperation writeOp){
          this.writeOp = writeOp;
      }

      @Override
      public void open(String uID) throws Exception{
      }

      @Override
      public void write(ZipInputStream zis){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            try{
                ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
                while(ze!=null){
                    File f = new File(writeOp.sink.unzipTarget + "/" + ze.getName());
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    int len;
                    while((len=zis.read(buffer))>0){
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                    fos.close();
                    this.totalUnzipped++;
                }
                zis.closeEntry();
                zis.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                //
            }

      }

      @Override
      public UnzipResult close() throws Exception{
          return new UnzipResult(this.totalUnzipped);
      }

      @Override
      public ZipFileWriteOperation getWriteOperation(){
          return writeOp;
      }


  }

  private static class UnzipResult implements Serializable{  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8504626439217544799L;
    final long filesUnziped;      
      public UnzipResult(long filesUnziped){
          this.filesUnziped=filesUnziped;
      }
  }
}
```

}

When I am trying to run the pipeline, I get a few errors:

> Building a Coder from the fallback CoderProvider failed: Cannot provide coder for type java.util.zip.ZipInputStream: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.protobuf.ProtoCoder$1@5717c37 could not provide a Coder for type java.util.zip.ZipInputStream: Cannot provide ProtoCoder because java.util.zip.ZipInputStream is not a subclass of com.google.protobuf.Message; com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder$1@68f4865 could not provide a Coder for type java.util.zip.ZipInputStream: Cannot provide SerializableCoder because java.util.zip.ZipInputStream does not implement Serializable.
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.TypedPValue.inferCoderOrFail(TypedPValue.java:195)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.TypedPValue.getCoder(TypedPValue.java:48)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PCollection.getCoder(PCollection.java:137)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.TypedPValue.finishSpecifying(TypedPValue.java:88)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:332)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:291)
>       at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:174)

Which coder do I need to assign to handle ZipInputStreams?

Thanks & BR
Philipp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coders are necessary so that a runner may materialize the `PCollection` to temporary storage and read it back, rather than holding it in memory. I can not think of a reasonable way to materialize a `ZipInputStream` object - this is a fundamental conceptual issue rather than a `Coder` API issue.

However, in your particular case, I think you can simply open the `ZipInputStream` in your `ZipWriter.write()` function, and make `ZipIO.Sink` be a `Sink<GcsPath>` rather than `Sink<ZipInputStream>`.

One more thing I noticed in your code: I suppose you plan to use this code with files located on GCS and with the Cloud Dataflow runner, rather than only the in-memory runner and local files. In that case, `java.io.File` will not transparently handle reading/writing to GCS - you'll need to use [GcsUtil](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/GcsUtil.java) for that.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same coder error when using GcsPath instead of ZipInputStream. Thanks & BR Philipp

Comment: Oh. My apologies, GcsPath is not marked Serializable (though I think it ought to be). Looks like you'll need to represent the path as `String`.